# iCLoud Safari Tabs don't sync between devices

Tags: icloud, safari

I have Macbook Air 2015 running Big Sur 11.0.1 and iPhone 6s Plus iOS 14.2 (and it seems that either ios 14 or Big Sur ruined everything because I remember that everything worked perfect on Mojave and ios 13).
I setup everything correctly (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202530)
I use the same appleID. Safari is checked in both iOS and MacOS iCloud settings. History works perfect, favorites works perfect. But I don't see on my iPhone which tabs are opened on Mac and the other way.
I rebooted both devices, I signed out and signed in back on both devices and nothing helps me.

Noticed another funny thing: when I open Safari on an iPhone - on Mac doc appears Safari icon for iPhone. So now I have 2 Safari icons in Dock - on for Mac and another one for ios. And when I click on ios icon - it opens the current webpage opened on an iphone. So icloud works, but why I can't see ALL tabs opened on any device like before?
[image]

Comment: Right now using iPhone I added some webpage to favorites and after a minute it appeared in favorites on Mac. But opening tab overview I can't see any websites. It is so frustrating

Comment: force restarting both devices doesn't help